# Will a MS Polymer Sealant bond to both PPE (polyphenylene ether) plastic and concrete to create a submersible watertight seat?

Tags: concrete, waterproofing, plastic, bonding

I'm researching a waterproof sealant that that will bond PPE (polyphenylene ether) plastic to concrete.  I embedded a PPE channel drain section in concrete for use as an intake for a pond pump (pictures available).  The basin is seeping water and i suspect the seepage is coming from the channel and the piping that penetrates the channel.  I am exploring different products to create a watertight seal between the channel and concrete.  I have tried “Flex Glue” but after its 24 hour cure time it easily detaches from the channel (i.e. does not bond).

Comment: HI, as phrased, this question is off-topic because product recommendation.  It would be best if you don't ask for a product, but a method to achieve your goal.  And people may respond with a product name, which is fine,

Answer (score 0):

Scuff the surface. Consider a primer like Sika 205 for applications like this below the water line. Consider a "marine grade" sealant designed for under water use. Pay particular attention to the sealant's range of application temperatures this time of year.